# python のpygameプログラムで、class Slider の命令が認識されません。

Tags: python, pygame

Pythonを「pythonゲームプログラミング　知っておきたい数学と物理の基本」にて勉強中の超初心者です。
標題の本（教科書）に記載に従って、下記のコードを入力し、「Run Module」にて実行したところ、エラーメッセージが表示され、「pygame window」と表示された、真黒な画面が表示され、しばらく待ちましたが、変化はありませんでした。
「SURFACE(.......)」、「main()」等の、入力位置を前後に移動してみましたが、同様のエラーメッセージが表示され、画面も同様に、真黒でした。教科書に記載されたような画面が表示されるようにするには、何が不足しているのでしょうか。
「class Slider」をインストールする必要があるのでしょうか。ご指導のほど、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

**エラーメッセージ抜粋**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\trg_function0.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\trg_function0.py", line 41, in main
    slider = Slider(Rect(20, 410, 360, 35), 0, 360, 0)
TypeError: Slider() takes no arguments
```

**入力したコード**
trg_function0.py

```
import sys
from math import sin, cos, radians
import pygame
from pygame.locals import Rect,QUIT, MOUSEMOTION, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP

pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 450))
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
class Slider:
    "スライダウィジェット"

def __init__(self, rect, min_value, max_value, value):
    self.rect = rect
    self.slider_rect = rect.copy()
    self.slider_rect.inflate_ip(-20, -20)
    self.knob_rect = rect.copy()
    self.knob_rect.move_ip(10, 0)
    self.knob_rect.width = 4
    self.min_value = min_value
    self.max_value = max_value
    self.value = value
    def draw(self):
         """ スライダを描画 """
    pygame.draw.rect(SURFACE, (225, 225, 225), self.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(SURFACE, (64, 64, 128), self.slider_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(SURFACE, (0, 0, 255), self.knob_rect)
    def set_pos(self, xpos):
        """ スライダ値を設定 """
        xpos = max(self.slider_rect.left, min(self.slider_rect.right, xpos))
        ypos = self.knob_rect.center[1]
        self.knob_rect.center = (xpos, ypos)
    def get_value(self):
        """ スライダ値を取得 """
        ratio = (self.knob_rect.center[0] - self.slider_rect.left) / self.slider_rect.width
        return(self.max_value - self.min_value) * ratio + self.min_value

def main():
    """ main routine """
    sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
    slider = Slider(Rect(20, 410, 360, 35), 0, 360, 0)
    mouse_down = false

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if mouse_down and slider.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        slider.set_pos(event.pos[0])
                elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        mouse_down = True
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    mouse_down = false
        SURFACE.fill((255, 255, 255))
        slider.draw()
        for index in range(0, 400, 10):
            pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (225, 225, 225), (0, index), (400, index))
            pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (225, 225, 225), (index, 0), (index, 400))
            pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (0, 0, 0), (0, 200), (400, 200))
            pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (0, 0, 0), (200, 0), (200, 400))
            pygame.draw.circle(SURFACE, (255, 0, 0), (200, 200), (150, 2))

        theta = slider.get_value()
        cos_v = round(cos(radians(theta)), 3)
        sin_v = round(sin(radians(theta)), 3)
        xpos = cos_v * 150 + 200
        ypos = sin_v * -150 + 200

        pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (0, 0, 192), (xpos, ypos), (xpos, 200))
        pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (0, 192, 0), (xpos, ypos), (200, ypos))
        pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, (192, 0, 0), (xpos, ypos), (200, 200))
        bmp = sysfont.render("cos:{}".format(cos_v), True, (0, 0, 192))
        SURFACE.blit(bmp, (xpos, 200))
        bmp = sysfont.render("sin:{}".format(sin_v), True, (0, 192, 0))
        SURFACE.blit(bmp, (200, ypos))

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

検索したら、該当書籍の該当部分が出てきたので見てみたら、まあ入力ミスですね。
質問記事のソースは書籍の記述と違っているので、以下を直してください。

- `class Slider:`の`def __init__(...):`メソッド全体のインデントを増やす
- `class Slider:`の`def draw(self):`メソッドの`pygame.draw.rect()`のインデントを増やす
- `def main():`の2か所の`mouse_down = false`の`false`は`False`と大文字で始める
- `def main():`の最初の`for`ループで`elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:`と`mouse_down = True`のインデントを減らす
- `def main():`の2つ目の`for`ループに含まれるのは2行の`pygame.draw.line()`だけ、その下の`pygame.draw.line()`と`pygame.draw.circle()`は`for`ループの外側へ(インデントを減らす)
- `def main():`の`pygame.draw.circle()`の後ろ2つのパラメータ`, (150, 2))`が余分な括弧に囲まれていたのを外して`, 150, 2)`にする

おまけ(見映えのため)

- `class Slider:`の`def draw(self):`,`def set_pos(self, xpos):`,`def get_value(self):`の前に空白行を挿入する

内容は書籍の記述そのものなので、全体の修正版記述は止めます。

書籍の該当部分の最後に以下の記述がありますが、プログラミングの勉強では「入力/転記ミス」に注意してください。

> 今の段階ではプログラムの内容を理解できなくても構いません。ただ、プログラムを入力・実行して、中心角とsin/cosの関係がどうなっているかしっかりと把握してください。

Comment: kunif様、さっそくの」ご回答、、一応宇うあありがとうございす。

Comment: kunif様、さっそくのご回答、ありがとうございます。ほかのプログラム同様、入力ミスが多く、反省しております。入力ミスを訂正し、インデントの箇所なども本とご指導を確認し、修正を行ったのですが、「Run Moduru」でのインデントエラーが出た個所をを修正し、「Run Module」を実行しますと、今度は「NameError: name 'self' is not defined」とのエラーメッセージとなっていまいまかた。まだまだ勉強不足ですので、これからもよろしくお願い申し上げます。それから、kunif様など、回答いただいた方への評価のやりかたが分かっておりませんので、このサイトの作法などお教えいただければ幸いです。

Comment: どこかで微妙に書籍の記述と合っていないのだと思われます。見較べて違いが無いように修正してください。空白とタブの混在に注意してください。評価については、回答欄左上に灰色の✔マークがありますので、それをクリックすれば回答を承認(有効と判断:複数回答があった場合はどれか一つだけ)したことになります。